# send dot clicks to server using html5

Tags: html, browser, canvas, svg, draw

I am trying to echo user input. Idea is user clicks the dots to draw a shape and then clicks submit. I receive the 'dots' he clicked, and then I reply back the dot numbers. example --

```
  A B C D E F G H I J
1 * * * * * * * * * *
2 * * * * * * * * * *
3 * * * * * * * * * *
4 * * * * * * * * * *
5 * * * * * * * * * *
```

If a user clicks the '+' ones --

```
  A B C D E F G H I J
1 * * * * * * * * * *
2 * * * * * + * + * *
3 * * * * * + * + * *
4 * * * * * * + * * *
5 * * * * * * * * * *
```

and then submits the page, I then give him - F2F3G4H3H2 (in sequence of how he clicked).

My issue is how to send the data to server? And, I can manage to do on click color change to make sure that the user clicked it. Or, even when he clicks, there is a line connecting the dots (like a stick shape).
How to do the same in HTML5, wherein every click he does on dots, is registered and then sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to encode the state and then send it using an [XMLHTTPRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/XMLHttpRequest/Using_XMLHttpRequest) to the server.